# Python logging duplicate log entries

Tags: python

I have a json config file and to register the custom logger inside of it, i do the following

```
logging.config.dictConfig(config)  
myLogger = logging.getLogger("myCustomLogger")
```

When I debug, I see that the first code line above calls getLogger on the logger object and registers a console handler with it.
I need a handle to the same logger object and thus, I call getLogger again which I think registers the same handler again.

when I log, the same log entry gets written twice on console.

I don't see a way to get a handle of logger object from logging.config.dictConfig.

The strange thing that I observed while debugging is that when the break point goes past the second line and I check the number of handlers associated with myLogger, it is only 1 handler.
This is how I check this on python console that comes with pydev eclipse plugin

```
myLogger.handlers[1]
```

It gives me an error saying index doesn't exist.

```
 myLogger.handlers[0] works fine
```

Pretty brand new to python, so out of ideas at this point. Does anyone know how to get around this problem ?

EDIT:

Here is the dict config json file

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": true,

    "formatters": {
        "custom": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(applicationName)s,%(applicationState)s] %(message)s"
        }

    },

    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "custom"
        }
    },

    "root": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "handlers": ["console"]
    },

    "loggers": {
        "myCustomLogger": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `config`?

Comment: i have shared it now.

Comment: There's only one "handler" in your config.

Comment: Can you post an example duplicated output as well? It might be both `root` and `console` are logging, you could add `"formatter": "custom"` to `root` and see the levels.

Comment: documentation says that every time you call getLogger, it adds a handler to that logger. So i am suspecting my 2 lines of code in the Question are adding the same handler twice to myCustomerLogger

Comment: i already have custom formatter applied to room through "handlers" : ["console"] as console handler has "formatter" : "custom". Is that what you meant ?

Comment: @Hary, ignore my comments then, showing example output might be helpful.

Comment: @zyxue Actually you are right about the root logger. I removed the root logger from the dict config and it just logged it once. In change change the handler of the root logger. However, it would act. Is there a way to suppress the root logger conditionally ?

Comment: @Hary, you can just remove `console` from `root`'s handlers

Comment: Actually I had to disable flask's default 'werkzeug' logger cuz it was creating some kind of issues with my default formatter. Good suggestion to remove console handler from root logger. thanks. So it root logger going to act no matter what ?

Comment: Are there any known side effects of deleting the root logger ?

Comment: Please answer the question instead of just keeping it as comment here and i'll mark it "answered". thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": true,

    "formatters": {
        "custom": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(applicationName)s,%(applicationState)s] %(message)s"
        }

    },

    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "custom"
        }
    },

    "root": {
        "level": "INFO",
        # this is the only difference from your original config file
        "handlers": []
    },

    "loggers": {
        "myCustomLogger": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

As for your question: "*So it root logger going to act no matter what?*" If it's not printing to the screen, then it's effectively doing nothing. The logging message is still being generated, but your other handler will need it anyway.